# Wrong IJavaProject returned

Tags: java, eclipse

An issue that I just encountered when I have multiple JAVA projects in workspace `Proj1` and `Proj2`.

For example: Both have the JRE System Library in their `build_path`, when I open `Proj2` in `Package Explorer` and select a node of any class within `rt.jar` (within JRE lib), I am getting project `Proj1` and not `Proj2` (`Proj1` appears above `Proj2` in the `Package Explorer`).

```java
ISelection selection = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getSelection();

if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
    Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();
    if (element instanceof IClassFile){
      IJavaProject jProject = ((IClassFile) element).getJavaProject();
      project = jProject.getProject();
     //returns 'Proj1' and not 'Proj2'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:
 `Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();`
is always returning the first project in package explorer.

Try with something like that:

`TreeSelection selection = (TreeSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
            Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
            if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable){
                try{
                    IProject project = (IProject)((IAdaptable)firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
...`

And then obtain the `IJavaProject` with:

`IJavaProject ijp = JavaCore.create(project);`

Comment: `((IAdaptable)firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class)` returns null

Comment: In my plugin, y can access the IJavaProject from PackageExplorer with that code.  If `firstElement` is not null, check available API for another options.

Comment: are you selecting a class file within a jar file of JRE library?

Comment: No, my scope is the project or its classes, `IFile` or `IProject` types. Hope my code helps you someway.

Comment: just to try to do it with class file ()you have it under JRE System library)